# VBScript - Renaming files using replace function and getbasename method

Tags: string, replace, vbscript, character

I don't have any problem when prepending characters or strings to a filename using the `Replace` function e.g.

```
j = prependstring
for each i in folder.files    
k = len(i.name)
i.name = replace(i.name, i.name, j & left(i.name, k))
```

Nor for that matter appending e.g.

```
j = appendstring
for each i in folder.files   
ext = fso.getextensionname(i)
k = instrrev(i.name,".")-1
i.name = replace(i.name, i.name, left(i.name, k) & " " & j & "." & ext)
```

However, using the following code,  if I try replace the entire `base name`, with a version where the leading letter of each word is capitalized I get a "File already exists" error.

```
option explicit
dim fso, folder, wshell, strpath, strname, i, abspath, base, ext, capstr

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set folder = fso.getfolder(".")

set wshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
strpath = wscript.scriptfullname
strname = fso.getfilename(strpath)

function wordcaps(strinput)
dim x 
for x = asc("a") to asc("z") 
strinput = replace(strinput, " " & chr(x), " " & ucase(chr(x))) 
next 
wordcaps = ucase(left(strinput, 1)) & mid(strinput, 2) 
end function 

for each i in folder.files
if i.name <> strname then
base=fso.getbasename(i)
capstr = wordcaps(base)
'wscript.echo capstr
i.name = replace(i.name, base, capstr)
end if
next
wscript.echo "Done!"
```

I can achieve the same objective using `MoveFile` method as shown below:

```
for each i in folder.files
if i.name <> strname then
abspath=fso.getabsolutepathname(i)
base=fso.getbasename(i)
ext=fso.getextensionname(i)
capstr = wordcaps(base)
fso.movefile abspath, folder & "\" & capstr & "." & ext
end if
next
wscript.echo "Done!"
```

I can't understand why does the `replace` version does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic fact: Windows file system is case insensitive (unless reconfigured) (cf. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx))

> Do not assume case sensitivity. For example, consider the names OSCAR,
>   Oscar, and oscar to be the same, even though some file systems (such
>   as a POSIX-compliant file system) may consider them as different. Note
>   that NTFS supports POSIX semantics for case sensitivity but this is
>   not the default behavior. For more information, see CreateFile.

The code needed to come to grips with this fact **and** to realize that .MoveFile (could involve copy) is less strict then .Name renaming (name change and nothing else):

```
Option Explicit

Const csFiNa = "a.txt"

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If goFS.FileExists(csFiNa) Then goFS.DeleteFile csFiNa
goFS.CreateTextFile csFiNa
WScript.Echo "Size of", csFiNa, ":", goFS.GetFile(csFiNa).Size
goFS.MoveFile csFiNa, UCase(csFiNa)
WScript.Echo "Moved", csFiNa, "to", UCase(csFiNa)
On Error Resume Next
 goFS.GetFile(csFiNa).Name = UCase(csFiNa)
 WScript.Echo "*** Error:", Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
```

output:

```
cscript 39537824.vbs
Size of a.txt : 0
Moved a.txt to A.TXT
*** Error: File already exists
```